# DigitalOcean Functions (AWS Layer, custom Libs, Lambda Container)

Tags: digital-ocean

DigitalOcean Functions looks good. But I would like to know:

Does DigitalOcean Functions have something like AWS Layer? How to import custom libs?

Does DO Function support: Building DigitalOcean Functions from Container Images? Like AWS Lambda Contaner

tnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Concerning using container images, DigitalOcean Functions does not support using container images as functions. Instead, you must use the DigitalOcean tooling ([`doctl`](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/how-to/create-functions/#deploy-a-function-in-the-current-namespace) or [App Platform's build process](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/how-to/deploy-to-app-platform/)) to build and deploy the functions. Function code ends up built and sometimes put into a ZIP file in a proprietary way before being uploaded to DigitalOcean, but this is an implementation detail you shouldn't worry about.

Concerning how to use custom libraries, I'm assuming you're talking about things like NPM packages on npmjs.com. You would follow the instructions in the documentation for each programming language supported. Each language supported right now supports using custom libraries, but the steps are different for each language:

- [Go](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/runtimes/go/#use-modules-and-dependencies)
- [Node.js (without bundling)](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/runtimes/node-js/#use-modules-and-dependencies)
- [Node.js (with bundling)](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/runtimes/node-js/#use-bundlers-to-package-source-files)
- [PHP](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/runtimes/php/#use-modules-and-dependencies)
- [Python](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/runtimes/python/#use-python-packages-and-dependencies)

Concerning using custom libraries from private repositories, such as a private organization on npmjs.com for Node.js functions or a private GitHub repo for Go functions, this is not supported. Custom libraries must be publicly accessible.

Note that, for Python, [some libraries are provided in the Functions runtime itself](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/runtimes/python/#use-packages-provided-by-the-runtime) and can therefore be imported by function code without having to be included in what is deployed. This helps with use cases like using large libraries (larger than the 48 MB deployed function size limit) like Pandas.